# Redirected request in NGINX to the diffrent site on the same server.Cant make it work (CORS)

Tags: laravel, nginx, request, cors

I am trying to set some request from my website **A** to redirect to the website **B**

This is my nginx config for site **A**:

```
location /api {

  add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
  add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
  add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Content-Range,Range';
  add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Content-Range,Range';
  add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
  add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain; charset=utf-8';

    return 301 http://site-B.dev\$request_uri;

}
```

Im getting this error in console:

> Failed to load
>   http://site-B.dev/api/route: Response
>   to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://site-A.dev' is therefore not allowed access.

Request Example:

```
Request URL:http://site-A.dev/api/route
Request Method:GET
Status Code:301 Moved Permanently
Remote Address:192.168.10.10:80
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade
Response Headers
view source
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Content-Range,Range
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:GET, POST, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Access-Control-Expose-Headers:DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Content-Range,Range
Access-Control-Max-Age:1728000
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:185
Content-Type:text/html
Content-Type:text/plain; charset=utf-8
Date:Tue, 17 Oct 2017 15:46:22 GMT
Location:http://site-B.dev/api/route
Server:nginx/1.13.3
Request Headers
view source
Accept:application/json
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:pl-PL,pl;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:X-PINGOTHER, Content-Type, Authorization, Content-Length, X-Requested-With
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:PUT,GET,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS
Connection:keep-alive
Cookie:laravel_session=eyJpdiI6IjFteWJUNmNPZVhZRGZ1cVNGdXB5Ync9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoicVdGV2Q3XC9lV09MbEd3MTRyK0dYcE94R1BJbjdid3VUZDVTMVg2ZlJPT0o5aUFjYTg5UXY0c3RGc2JRYlJMVTc4eFk5bTViMGk0UmJZZUxZK2ZCeGZBPT0iLCJtYWMiOiIxMjZjNjg4ZDIwM2ZiYjc5Y2RhYmU3MjI3NTQxMmNmMTFiYWQxYWNlYzk5MWY0ZTZhYzQ5YTkyMGM0MDMzZDJlIn0%3D
Host:dite-A.dev
Referer:http://site-A.dev/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36
```

Redirected request:

```
Request URL:http://site-B.dev/api/route
Request Method:OPTIONS
Status Code:200 OK
Remote Address:192.168.10.10:80
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade
Response Headers
view source
Allow:GET,HEAD
Cache-Control:no-cache, private
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date:Tue, 17 Oct 2017 15:46:22 GMT
Server:nginx/1.13.3
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
Request Headers
view source
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:pl-PL,pl;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Access-Control-Request-Headers:access-control-allow-headers,access-control-allow-methods
Access-Control-Request-Method:GET
Connection:keep-alive
Host:site-B.dev
Origin:http://site-A.dev
Referer:http://site-A.dev
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36
```

Its strange because im getting success responses but they are empty,if i send request direct to the site-B im getting normal response with proper data.

Is there any solution for my problem?What is wrong with this,why i have such error in the console even if i add `Acess-Control-Allow-Origin` header?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the error code, it looks you dont have any setup configured to handle preflight requests, the request type will be OPTIONS, in your nginx configuration add a similar block to handle OPTIONS

```
    location / {
     if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
         add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
         add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
         add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Content-Range,Range';
         add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Content-Range,Range';
         add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
         add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain; charset=utf-8';
         add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
         return 204;
     }
```